# Whether the bot get AutoUpdated for end users?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We are having a bot integrated with MS Teams.  Currently, the bot doesn't have command menus. We are going to implement the command menus in that bot. Hence I have a doubt that, once we deploy the change with command menus in production, will the bot get auto-updated for end-users? Will they be able to see the command menus without re-installing the bot?

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If there are changes in the [capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/capabilities-overview) or addition of [bot's commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#botscommandlists), you need to update the manifest and manifest version. Once it is done you can update the app following this doc -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/upload-custom-apps#update

If the there is only code changes you don't need to update the app on Microsoft Teams. It will take the latest deployed version automatically.